# Does a filename in Ubuntu starting with "readme" automatically become a readme document type?

Tags: files, filesystem, file-format

I'm working on a tomcat project so I saved a jsp file with the name of `readmessages.jsp` with `sublime-text editor`.

When I opened and saw its type (because it was displaying a readme icon on top of the `jsp` file), it was - README document (text/x-readme). I even tried saving it with Gedit and Atom but all in vain.

But then I changed the **filename** and it just worked out! I renamed the file from `readmessages.jsp` to `temp.jsp` and checked its file type. It was - HTML document.

I don't think it's because of the code typos in that `jsp file` because the same results were given back from other files too.

Please explain why files starting with "readme" (as in, **readme**ssages.jsp) become *README document (text/x-readme)* automatically in Ubuntu.

Is there a fix or workaround for saving files with different file type if they have a "readme" phrase in them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html and scripts are also plain text so the file type hasn't changed, just weird mojo about subclass icon decisions,

I found something that may help you:

Save the following as `jsp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/x-jsp">
    <comment>JSP file</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.jsp"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then open a terminal and run

```
xdg-mime install --novendor jsp.xml
```

Now all files with the extension `.jsp` should have the MIME type `text/x-jsp`.

See Shared MIME-info Database if you want to learn more about how MIME types are defined.